# In the EU is it possible to ask to transfer money from retirement funds from one country to the other? (Italy -> Austria)

Tags: retirement-funds

In Italy there are two statal retirement funds:

- Gestione ordinaria
- Gestione separata

Is it possible to move all the contributes I've payed to the second one from Italy to Austria?

[This](http://www.inps.it/portale/default.aspx?lastMenu=0&iMenu=1&iiDServizio=264) is the page of the Italian National Institute of Social Security

Comment: This question is already answered in [Withdrawing of retirement funds in EU](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/241/withdrawing-of-retirement-funds-in-eu)

Comment: @vartec: I think this is more specific because "Gestione separata" is not a normal retirement fund.

Comment: @vartec we are talking about transfering the retirement funds to another plan before retiring, in order to have only one fund when you retire, The question you point is about retiring and aggregating many different funds you may have. So the two questions are not related at all.