# Moving of retirement funds from Italy to Austria

Tags: eu, austria, retirement-funds, italy

I've migrated from Italy to Austria. I don't trust Italy and I would prefer to migrate the money I have in my retirement fund in italy to austria. Is it that possible in EU?

Another option could be to withdraw the money from the Italian retirement fund to a bank or a private retirement fund.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something that's governed by EU law. Assuming not, it'll be entirely specific to the rules of each country

Comment: @gagravarr not only countries but also pension funds, since in some EU countries those are private organisations

Comment: You can either get paid from each of the 10 countries or you can consolidate your commitments into one countries account. But most of the time you cannot take portions(only the whole sum) and most of the time you do not even see the money , the just say where you want to move it to, country, company etc.

Comment: well then you should apply to get your contributions moved over to your country of final residence - usually short periods like that, you can sometimes get TAX refunds too.

Comment: @vartec: what you mean? we can split if you want..

Comment: @Revious: I mean one thing is if it's possible to withdraw, another is how is pension from multiple EU countries handled.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal finance rather then migrating.

Comment: @Karlson: mmm.. I'm not so sure. The reason for which I want to withdraw that money is related with the fact I've migrated. I will try to edit the question to show this fact.

Comment: I've answered for the specific case of *transferring*. In this case (and probably in the case of withdrawing), I think you only need to focus on which money the country is coming *from*. This reduces the number of permutations to something potentially manageable...

Comment: @Benjol: thanks, they come from Italy to Austria..

Comment: @Revious, I think that in that case you should add tags for the countries concerned. And as it stands, the title is probably too broad too, unless someone can show that there is a 'one-size-fits-all' answer for Europe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Q*: What happens if someone works in 10 countries to his retirement?

If they happen to be 10 *EU* countries, then in the last country that person worked in he should apply for pension and get pension combined from all the countries he worked in.

As [Europa.eu portal explains](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/retire-abroad/state-pensions-abroad/index_en.htm),
if you've worked in several EU countries, you may have accumulated pension rights in each of them, but you only apply in one, which ought to take care of aggregating them.

> When the time comes for you to claim your pension, you'll have to
> apply in the country where you're living - unless you have never
> worked there. In this case, you should apply where you last worked.
>
> That country is then responsible for processing your claim and
> bringing together records of your contributions from all the countries
> you worked in.
>
> [...]
>
> If you've worked in several EU countries, each country's pension
> authority will first calculate your pension using its own rules, based
> on the contributions you paid there (known as independent benefit).

---

> *Q*: Is it possible in EU to withdraw a portion of the contributions for
> retirement?

This depends on individual regulations in each country. As far as I know, most European countries do *not* allow withdrawal of retirement contributions.