# Is it possible to transfer my pension out of a UK fund, and if so, how to go about it?

Tags: united-kingdom, retirement-funds

I worked for several years for a UK company, and have a corresponding amount of pension in their pension scheme. Now it looks like I'm pretty unlikely to return (and even if I do, it's a pain to have to maintain two relationships with pension funds), I'd like to work out how I can go about transferring those funds to my company pension scheme here.

I'm deliberately leaving the 'here' vague, as I suspect the answer depends more on the UK than the target country.

Comment: Note, this question was inspired by [this](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/241) one, which subsequently had its scope refined.

Answer (score 7):

To move money out of a UK pension fund you have to provide proof that the target fund (where you are intending to move the money to) satisfies UK requirements. The key term here is **QROPS** (*Qualifying Recognised Overseas Pension Scheme*). If the target fund is a QROPS (there's a non-exhaustive but fairly comprehensive list [here](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/pensionschemes/qrops.pdf)(pdf)) then it

> can receive the transfer of UK Pension Benefits without incurring an unauthorised payment and scheme sanction charge.

If the target fund is *not* a QROPS, you can suggest that they become one - [this page](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/pensionschemes/qrops.htm) on http://www.hmrc.gov.uk explains how (basically there is a fairly simple [form to download](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/pensionschemes/apss251.pdf), fill in and send, or you can do it online).

Comment: Wow. How did you ask and answer the question at the same time?

Comment: @ppumkin, when you ask a question, there's a little checkbox at the bottom of the page 'Answer your own question' :)

Comment: Ha.. I saw that but never actually used it before. Cool